# Linking and include problems with popper cpp

Tags: c++, linker, include-path, poppler

After downloading, compiling and installing `poppler-21.02.0`,
I'm having difficulty in including header files and linking the library.

O.S. : Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop

in `.bashrc` file :

```
export CPATH=/usr/local/include/

export CPLUS_INCLUDE=/usr/local/include

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/include/poppler

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/lib
```

If I put in docOpening.cpp :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "/home/marco/poppler-21.02.0/cpp/poppler-document.h"
#include "/home/marco/poppler-21.02.0/cpp/poppler-page.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

The compilation seems ok:

```
popplerCpp$ g++ -std=c++11 -L /usr/local/lib docOpening.cpp -o docOpening -lpoppler 
-lpoppler-qt5 -lpoppler-glib

/popplerCpp$ ls -lah
total 24K
drwxr-xr-x  2 marco marco 4,0K mar  1 15:55 .
drwxr-xr-x 21 marco marco 4,0K mar  1 12:15 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 marco marco 8,6K mar  1 15:55 docOpening
-rw-r--r--  1 marco marco  601 mar  1 15:55 docOpening.cpp
```

When I add in main() function this line:
`poppler::document *doc = poppler::document::load_from_file("")`

I get this error :

```
g++ -std=c++11 -L /usr/local/lib docOpening.cpp -o docOpening -lpoppler -lpoppler-qt5
-lpoppler-glib
/tmp/ccTelEVC.o: In function `main':
docOpening.cpp:(.text+0x6f): undefined reference to    
`poppler::document::load_from_file(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,  
std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, 
std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,    
std::allocator<char> > const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Having installed the poppler library :

```
(base) marco@pc01:/usr/local/include/poppler$ ls -lah
total 20K
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4,0K mar  1 12:08 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root 4,0K mar  1 12:08 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4,0K mar  1 12:08 cpp
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4,0K mar  1 12:08 glib
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4,0K mar  1 12:08 qt5

(base) marco@pc01:/usr/local/include/poppler/cpp$ ls -lah
total 68K
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4,0K mar  1 12:08 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4,0K mar  1 12:08 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1,8K feb  1 22:23 poppler-destination.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4,3K feb  1 22:23 poppler-document.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1,5K feb  1 22:23 poppler-embedded-file.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2,1K feb  1 22:23 poppler-font.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2,1K feb  1 22:23 poppler-font-private.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3,4K feb  1 22:23 poppler-global.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1,9K feb  1 22:23 poppler-image.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5,9K feb  1 22:23 poppler-page.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2,1K feb  1 22:23 poppler-page-renderer.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1,8K feb  1 22:23 poppler-page-transition.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1,9K feb  1 22:23 poppler-rectangle.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1,6K feb  1 22:23 poppler-toc.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1,2K mar  1 11:00 poppler-version.h

(base) marco@pc01:/usr/local/lib$ ls -lah | grep poppler
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    19 mar  1 12:08 libpoppler-cpp.so -> libpoppler-cpp.so.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    23 mar  1 12:08 libpoppler-cpp.so.0 -> libpoppler-cpp.so.0.9.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  3,0M mar  1 12:08 libpoppler-cpp.so.0.9.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    20 mar  1 12:08 libpoppler-glib.so -> libpoppler-glib.so.8
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    25 mar  1 12:08 libpoppler-glib.so.8 -> libpoppler-glib.so.8.19.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  5,2M mar  1 12:06 libpoppler-glib.so.8.19.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    19 mar  1 12:08 libpoppler-qt5.so -> libpoppler-qt5.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    24 mar  1 12:08 libpoppler-qt5.so.1 -> libpoppler-qt5.so.1.27.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   14M mar  1 12:06 libpoppler-qt5.so.1.27.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    17 mar  1 12:08 libpoppler.so -> libpoppler.so.107
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    21 mar  1 12:08 libpoppler.so.107 -> libpoppler.so.107.0.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   31M mar  1 12:05 libpoppler.so.107.0.0
```

I tried to include the two header files in this way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "poppler-document.h"
#include "poppler/poppler-page.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

But I get:

```
 such file or directory
    3 | #include "poppler-document.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

The same error if I switch from `""` to `<>`  :

```
#include <poppler-document.h>
#include <poppler/poppler-page.h>
```

Luckily, I previously saved the installation log:

```
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "RelWithDebInfo"
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libpoppler.so.107.0.0
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libpoppler.so.107
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libpoppler.so
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/poppler.pc
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/poppler-qt5.pc
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/poppler-glib.pc
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/poppler-cpp.pc
-- Installing: /usr/local/bin/pdftoppm
-- Set runtime path of "/usr/local/bin/pdftoppm" to ""
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/man/man1/pdftoppm.1
-- Installing: /usr/local/bin/pdftocairo
-- Set runtime path of "/usr/local/bin/pdftocairo" to ""
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/man/man1/pdftocairo.1
-- Installing: /usr/local/bin/pdfdetach
-- Set runtime path of "/usr/local/bin/pdfdetach" to ""
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/man/man1/pdfdetach.1
-- Installing: /usr/local/bin/pdfattach
-- Set runtime path of "/usr/local/bin/pdfattach" to ""
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/man/man1/pdfattach.1
-- Installing: /usr/local/bin/pdffonts
-- Set runtime path of "/usr/local/bin/pdffonts" to ""
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/man/man1/pdffonts.1
-- Installing: /usr/local/bin/pdfimages
-- Set runtime path of "/usr/local/bin/pdfimages" to ""
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/man/man1/pdfimages.1
-- Installing: /usr/local/bin/pdfinfo
-- Set runtime path of "/usr/local/bin/pdfinfo" to ""
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/man/man1/pdfinfo.1
-- Installing: /usr/local/bin/pdfsig
-- Set runtime path of "/usr/local/bin/pdfsig" to ""
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/man/man1/pdfsig.1
-- Installing: /usr/local/bin/pdftops
-- Set runtime path of "/usr/local/bin/pdftops" to ""
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/man/man1/pdftops.1   
-- Installing: /usr/local/bin/pdftotext
-- Set runtime path of "/usr/local/bin/pdftotext" to ""
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/man/man1/pdftotext.1
-- Installing: /usr/local/bin/pdftohtml
-- Set runtime path of "/usr/local/bin/pdftohtml" to ""
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/man/man1/pdftohtml.1
-- Installing: /usr/local/bin/pdfseparate
-- Set runtime path of "/usr/local/bin/pdfseparate" to ""
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/man/man1/pdfseparate.1
-- Installing: /usr/local/bin/pdfunite
-- Set runtime path of "/usr/local/bin/pdfunite" to ""
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/man/man1/pdfunite.1
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libpoppler-glib.so.8.19.0
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libpoppler-glib.so.8
-- Set runtime path of "/usr/local/lib/libpoppler-glib.so.8.19.0" to
""
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libpoppler-glib.so
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/poppler/glib/poppler-action.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/poppler/glib/poppler-date.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/poppler/glib/poppler-document.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/poppler/glib/poppler-page.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/poppler/glib/poppler-attachment.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/poppler/glib/poppler-form-field.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/poppler/glib/poppler-annot.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/poppler/glib/poppler-layer.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/poppler/glib/poppler-macros.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/poppler/glib/poppler-movie.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/poppler/glib/poppler-media.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/poppler/glib/poppler.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/poppler/glib/poppler-structure- 
element.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/poppler/glib/poppler-enums.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/poppler/glib/poppler-features.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libpoppler-qt5.so.1.27.0
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libpoppler-qt5.so.1
-- Set runtime path of "/usr/local/lib/libpoppler-qt5.so.1.27.0" to ""
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libpoppler-qt5.so
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/poppler/qt5/poppler-qt5.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/poppler/qt5/poppler-link.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/poppler/qt5/poppler-annotation.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/poppler/qt5/poppler-form.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/poppler/qt5/poppler-optcontent.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/poppler/qt5/poppler-export.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/poppler/qt5/poppler-page-
transition.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/poppler/qt5/poppler-media.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/poppler/qt5/poppler-version.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libpoppler-cpp.so.0.9.0
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libpoppler-cpp.so.0
-- Set runtime path of "/usr/local/lib/libpoppler-cpp.so.0.9.0" to ""
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libpoppler-cpp.so
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/poppler/cpp/poppler-destination.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/poppler/cpp/poppler-document.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/poppler/cpp/poppler-embedded-file.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/poppler/cpp/poppler-font.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/poppler/cpp/poppler-font-private.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/poppler/cpp/poppler-global.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/poppler/cpp/poppler-image.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/poppler/cpp/poppler-page.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/poppler/cpp/poppler-page-renderer.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/poppler/cpp/poppler-page-  
transition.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/poppler/cpp/poppler-rectangle.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/poppler/cpp/poppler-toc.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/poppler/cpp/poppler-version.h
```

With

```
#include <iostream>
#include <poppler-document.h>
#include <poppler/poppler-page.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

If I use `-I /usr/local/include/poppler/cpp`  I get the same error:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -I /usr/local/include/poppler/cpp -L /usr/local/lib 
docOpening.cpp -o docOpening -lpoppler -lpoppler-qt5 -lpoppler-glib
docOpening.cpp:7:10: fatal error: poppler/poppler-page.h: No such file    
or directory
    7 | #include <poppler/poppler-page.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Thanks to @JHBonarius I solved one problem: the `include` of header files:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <poppler-document.h>
#include <poppler-page.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
  return 0;
}

g++ -std=c++11 -I /usr/local/include/poppler/cpp -L /usr/local/lib 
docOpening.cpp -o docOpening -lpoppler -lpoppler-qt5 -lpoppler-glib


ls -la
total 24
drwxr-xr-x  2 marco marco 4096 mar  1 16:46 .
drwxr-xr-x 21 marco marco 4096 mar  1 12:15 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 marco marco 8784 mar  1 16:46 docOpening
-rw-r--r--  1 marco marco  662 mar  1 16:46 docOpening.cpp
```

Adding this line :

```
`poppler::document *doc = 
poppler::document::load_from_file("/.../");` 


#include <iostream>
#include <poppler-document.h>
#include <poppler-page.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    poppler::document *doc = 
poppler::document::load_from_file("//");
  return 0;
}

 g++ -std=c++11 -I /usr/local/include/poppler/cpp -L /usr/local/lib 
docOpening.cpp -o docOpening -lpoppler -lpoppler-qt5 -lpoppler-glib
/tmp/ccgU0a4i.o: In function `main':
 docOpening.cpp:(.text+0x6f): undefined reference to    
`poppler::document::load_from_file(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char,  
std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&,    
std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,  
std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, 
std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How to solve the `include` and `linking` ?

Comment: I think you need to add  `/usr/local/include/poppler/cpp` to your include directories. Although then `#include <poppler/poppler-page.h>` would still not work

Comment: @drescherjm I've just put the complete installation log in the post above. May be with that it's easier to spot what I'm doing wrongly, and how to solve the problem. Thank you for helping

Comment: I don't think any of your problems are related to installation of poppler

Comment: You're already using `-L /usr/local/lib`. So you must understand how to link to the other directory?

Comment: @JHBonarius What am I doing wrongly here:  `g++ -std=c++11 -I /usr/local/include/poppler/cpp -L /usr/local/lib docOpening.cpp -o docOpening -lpoppler -lpoppler-qt5 -lpoppler-glib`   ?

Comment: Ah, new info. Well next problem also seems quite clear `#include <poppler/poppler-page.h>` <-- there is no `poppler` directory... the file is just in the path. Thus `#include <poppler-page.h>`

Comment: @JHBonarius Yes. That solved the `include` problem.  Any ideas about how the linker problem? `g++ -std=c++11 -I /usr/local/include/poppler/cpp -L /usr/local/lib docOpening.cpp -o docOpening -lpoppler -lpoppler-qt5 -lpoppler-glib`

Comment: [does this help](http://www.richelbilderbeek.nl/CppLinkErrorUndefinedReferenceToPoppler.htm)?

Comment: @JHBonarius It suggests to do `-L/usr/local/lib -lpoppler-qt4` . I do not see any differences from `g++ -std=c++11 -I /usr/local/include/poppler/cpp  -L/usr/local/lib docOpening.cpp -o docOpening -lpoppler -lpoppler-qt5 -lpoppler-glib`. May be the ordering of the single compilation's elements has to be adjusted?